# Callbacks, completion handler with multiple parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I reverse geocode in a few places in my map and I wanted to wrap it to some common method.  What I have is this as a starting point that works:

```
func reverseGeocodeLocation(location: CLLocation, completion: (CLPlacemark) -> Void) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        
        // Check for returned placemarks
        if let placemarks = placemarks where placemarks.count > 0 {
            let topResult = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark

            completion(topResult)
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I want to add another parameter to my completion method that would return the error to my view like so:

```
func reverseGeocodeLocation(location: CLLocation, completion: (CLPlacemark, NSError) -> Void) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        
        // Check for returned placemarks
        if let placemarks = placemarks where placemarks.count > 0 {
            let topResult = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark

            completion(topResult, error)
        }
    }
}
```

If error is `nil`, then my `completion(topResult, error)` will fail because error is nil with bad access.  But I cannot do this since the parameters are not matching the completion handler.

```
if error != nil {
    completion(topResult)
} else {
    completion(...) // do something with the error
}
```

So if I have a nil error, how would I call my completion handler?

Comment: I think the error should have been an optional in that case? Also what is the full signature of geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation  method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you own definition of your completion header your can define it normally with optional `NSError?` So it will not cause errors and will require unwrapping.  Moreover recent definition of `CLGeocodeCompletionHandler` also uses optional array and error:

```
typealias CLGeocodeCompletionHandler = ([CLPlacemark]?, NSError?) -> Void
```

Comment: Wouldn't I still have to do this if there was no error: `completion(topResult, nil)`

Comment: Yes, NSError? Allows you to pass nil without issues